# Codeigniter select previous day from the database record

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have some problem to get previous day of the record from the database. My table look like this :

```
id   total       trx_date    
1   | 100 | 2019-05-13 04:03:03 |    
2   | 200 | 2019-05-13 14:13:48 |
3   | 300 | 2019-05-12 10:23:37 |
4   | 100 | 2019-05-10 12:14:14 | <<<<<<<<<<<
5   | 200 | 2019-05-10 15:23:38 |
6   | 400 | 2019-05-10 19:33:56 |
```

I'm able to take the previous date if there's no gap between the date, but I'm failed to get the previous date if there's no record on the previous date.

My code :

```php
$this->db->select("id, total, trx_date")
     ->from("trx_table")
     ->where('date(trx_date)', date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 day')) )
     ->order_by("id","DESC")
     ->get();
```

So I expect to get the previous day of the record, not the previous day of the current date. Can you guys help me to resolve this issue?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe do `WHERE trx_date < NOW() ORDER BY trx_date DESC LIMIT 1`. So the latest date earlier than today will be returned.

Comment: You can try `select id, total, trx_date
     from trx_table
     where date(trx_date) =  date((SELECT max(trx_date) FROM trx_table))
     order_by("id","DESC")`

Comment: @AbraCadaver thank you! you save my day!

Comment: @AbraCadaver for my case, i should use date('Y-m-d') in WHERE clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select dates earlier than today, but sort them descending and get only one.  This will return the latest date earlier than today:

```
SELECT id, total, trx_date
       FROM trx_table 
       WHERE trx_date < NOW()
       ORDER BY trx_date DESC
       LIMIT 1
```